# rake db:multi:migrate DATABASE=configuration error with JRuby, mysql, riak

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, jruby

JRuby 1.7.1 and Rails 3.2.11

In terminal I'm running "rake db:multi:migrate DATABASE=configuration" but I keep getting the error below meaning as far as I can tell that the configuration database is not being created.

```
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
(4.0ms)  SET SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL=0
rake aborted!
The driver encountered an unknown error: 
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'configuration'
```

The specific steps I'm supposed to follow to get this set up are:

```
mysql.server start

mysql -uroot
create user 'funapp_test'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'funapp_test';
grant all privileges on *.* to 'funapp_test'@'localhost' with grant option;
create user 'funapp'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '#sh4r3!';
grant all privileges on *.* to 'funapp'@'localhost' with grant option;

RAILS_ENV=test rake db:create
RAILS_ENV=development rake db:create

mysql -uroot funapp_test < db/structure.sql
mysql -uroot funapp < db/structure.sql

rake db:multi:migrate DATABASE=funapp
rake db:multi:migrate DATABASE=configuration
```

database.yml

```
development:
adapter: mysql
database: funapp
username: funapp
password: "#sh4r3!"
host: 127.0.0.1
pool: 5
xa: false

test: &test
adapter: mysql
database: funapp_test
username: funapp_test
password: "funapp_test"
host: 127.0.0.1
pool: 5
xa: false

configuration_development:
adapter: mysql
database: configuration
username: funapp
password: "#sh4r3!"
host: 127.0.0.1
pool: 5
xa: false

configuration_test:
adapter: mysql
database: configuration_test
username: funapp_test
password: "funapp_test"
host: 127.0.0.1
pool: 5
xa: false
```

Any ideas on what I can do to get this fixed? I've tried doing rake db:drop and rake db:migrate, as well as rake db:create:all (which gives me a Riak::Node configuration must include :source and :root keys. error) Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, much simpler than I thought

```
mysql -uroot
create database configuration;
create database configuration_test;
```